# Find the dimension of the space of tensor fields

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tensors, differential-forms

What shown belove is a reference from *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres

[image]

So we observe that we can structure the set $\Omega^k(V)$ of $k$-tensor field defined over the open set $V$ of $\Bbb R^n$ to a vector space letting
$$
[\omega+\eta](x):=\omega(x)+\eta(x)\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,[a\cdot\omega](x):=a\cdot\omega(x)
$$
for any $x\in V$ where $\omega$ and $\eta$ are $k$-tensor field and $a$ is a scalar.
So we define now a function $⊛$ from $\underset{k\,\,\,\text{times}}{\underbrace{\Omega^1(V)\times...\times\Omega^1(V)}}$ to $\Omega^k(V)$ through the equation
$$
[\omega_1\circledast...\circledast\omega_k](x):=\omega_1(x)\otimes...\otimes\omega_k(x)
$$
for any $x\in V$. So since the collection
$$
\mathfrak F:=\big\{\tilde{\phi}_{i_1}(x)\otimes...\otimes\tilde{\phi}_{i_k}(x):i_1,...,i_k=1,...,n\big\}
$$
is for each $x\in V$ a base for $\mathcal L^k\big(\mathcal T_x(\Bbb R^n)\big)$ then the tensor field of the colletion
$$
\mathfrak T:=\big\{\tilde{\phi}_{i_1}\circledast...\circledast\tilde{\phi}_{i_k}(x):i_1,...,i_k=1,...,n\big\}
$$
are linearly independent but unfortunately I did not be able to prove that they span $\Omega^k(V)$ so that I  thought that the dimesion of this space is infinite. So I ask to find the dimension of the space of tensor fields defined over an open set $V$ either over a manifold $M$. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Yes, $\Omega^k$'s are infinite dimensional as $\Bbb R$ vector spaces (for example, $\Omega^0(V)$ is the space of all smooth functions on $V$). But, $\Omega^k(V)$ is finitely-generated as $C^\infty(V)$-module. I believe it is free with rank $n^k$.

Comment: Where is the notation $\Omega^k(V)$ defined in Munkres? To use this for all $k$-tensors is shocking.

Comment: @TedShifrin Munkres define the symbolo $\Omega^k$ at the page $255$ that I do not report above in the reference. Anyway $\Omega^k$ is not finite dimensional, right?

Comment: I'm used to $\Omega^k$ being used for differential forms or even holomorphic differential forms. At any rate, the vector space of $k$-tensors on a manifold is a (very) infinite-dimensional vector space, but @feynhat is of course correct that it is a module over the smooth functions of dimension $n^k$.

Comment: Okay, all clear. Thanks too much for the answer!